Weather on a Flat, Infinite Sea
Imagine a vast sea, stretching out to encompass the horizon much like a real sea. But unlike such a sea, this sea sits upon a flat plain, and stretches out over 100 million miles in each direction(except for the shore of course). A day begins with a glow spreading from one horizon to eventually encompass the whole sky with an even light. This diminishes after 12 hours, followed by 12 hours of starlit, moonless night.
Some things to note for clarity;

This flat plain that the ocean stretches on has a maximum depth of 10,000 feet, and the atmosphere over this sea extends above the water only 10,000 feet.
We will say there is a hard barrier at the top of the atmosphere, keeping the air in. Why is beyond the scope of this question.
Gravity is equal to Earth's gravity at all points under the ocean without variation.
The daylight radiation is equal to a tropical summer day on earth.
The light begins on the east horizon, moving across the sea toward the west. Any given point on the ocean will experience a total of 12 hours of day and 12 hours of night.
There are no landmasses in this sea, be they islands, continents, or subsurface mountain ranges. Only the flat bottom of the ocean.

My question is this; What weather(waves, winds, storms) would form in such an environment.

To be clear, you mean the whole planet is ocean, correct?

@RHF - I think they're making it clear that this is not a planet, but an infinite plane.

Yes, to be clear it IS NOT A PLANET, but is instead a fixed infinite plane with only one source of gravity.

I'm not sure the depth of answer you're looking for. Do you want to work with what you've given us, or a more detailed analysis? Does the whole ocean get the same radiation and twilight-cycle at exactly the same time - are there no local variations? Also, what's the maximum and minimum temperatures? What's the height and rate of change of density of the atmosphere? Does the "edge" suddenly end in vacuum or some kind of forcefield or barrier? Is there tea?

@Escapeddentalpatient. Fair question. I am mostly interested in what I have put down, but I don't mind more detailed answers if anyone wants. (Continued)

(part 2) In answer to some of those questions, the thing is I don't know. It's part of a RPG story world, and I am just thinking king through the impacts. If I want, I'll just handwaved it, but I was curious about the internal consistency. The thing is, I don't know if there is a hard barrier or a vacuum(leaning toward a barrier). I'm leaning towards a single day night cycle, but the other option would be determined by local worlds that you sail to on this plane, but "close to" is a fairly amorphous concept. Density and temperature--no idea.

So there's probably no tea then. OK. It's tough, but we can give you an answer which covers a possible range of conditions.... that would offer you flexibility. The powers-that-be might consider this too broad and underspecified at present, so beware of closure because of that.

Ok! Any changes that can be made, let me know. For now, I'll just add a few notes.

@Escapeddentalpatient. UPDATE: Made some changes, deciding to go with the atmospheric barrier, and then also had the light move across the length of the ocean from one end to the other. So night and day is not universal. Hope that helps.

I was rather looking forward to tea! That said, this is a very interesting question indeed!

I'd like to take a crack at this, but I need a few more bits of information. (a) What are the actual dimensions of the sea? You say infinite, then you say 100 million miles, then you say "except for the shore, of course." Can you provide a map showing actual landmass placement and dimensions? Is this something like Niven's Ringworld? (b) Is the sun identical to Sol? Or does the light progress as a bar across a square surface, 12 hours peak-to-peak? (c) Is there no volcanism? Thanks!

if have edges and mass then water will try to be a ball in center of Your plane. Adjusting for bottom rock and "air barrier" Your plane will loooks like: desert for around 20m miles, then ocean deep 0-20k feets, then around 40m miles ocean deep for 20k feet with force field n top and rock at bottom then ocean deep 0-20k feets then 20m miles desert... You need a lot of magic.

Just in case you don't realise this, you don't actually need the barrier at the top of the sky. If there's no barrier the air will just thin out until it becomes a vacuum, just like it does on Earth. Of course if you want the barrier there then no problem!

Without permanent temperature differentials across the water plain, the whole place gets the same daily total insolation, you wouldn't have any permanent ocean currents. Not related to the weather but this means that the water will be anoxic at depth and life as we know it will have serious issues surviving.
What you will see is weak, transient, fluid circulation events on a daily cycle, the subsolar point will be slightly hotter than the areas around it at any given point creating a relatively high level of evaporation and atmospheric convection above the point of maximum radiation absorption. This is going to produce an upwelling in both the atmosphere and the underlying ocean but not particularly strong ones. The evaporated moisture is going to form clouds as it rises but without Coriolis these are going to simply rise to their dew point and then dump their load. Rather than hurricanes etc... there will simply be relatively shortlived ranks of clouds behind the subsolar point that bleed out their water over the course of the afternoon and the night that follows, dawn should find the sky clear. I would expect overnight fog to be a given since the ocean is always going to be warmer than the air after the sun goes down and surface evaporation should continue.
Waves are going to be minimal except where the winds feeding into the subsolar low pressure cell are active, the waves that are "chasing the sun" (approaching the subsolar point in the same direction as the subsolar point is moving across the surface) have the ability to build on themselves somewhat and will be larger than those coming the other way.
Oops, I hadn't done the math, the solar radiation sweep is moving so fast that tropical intensity radiation is insufficient to create a meaningful energy budget for almost any weather phenomena to form. You'd need to be looking at something like being 1AU from Sirius A to get any major weather. You would still get waves if the radiation source is a star though, gravity induced like a tide but going millions of miles an hour.

I don't think there's a subsolar point, on account of there being no Sun.

@elemtilas There is "daylight radiation" that sweeps across the sea the subsolar "point" may in fact be a line across the whole plain but it does come and go and therefore must have a peak energy input intensity.

A pretty fat line! We've only got 12 hours to fill 100 million miles worth of sky with light and warmth!

@elemtilas So a very fast moving line, there will be very little weather whatsoever.

The line/zone would be moving at 8.3 million miles per hour!

K. I was hoping for some weather, so what if the daylight region is only the size of the earth, one comes every 12 hours, but there is more than one?

@Danvad There are no drivers of big weather in this situation, you won't get big weather.  Weather is driven by differences and you have a huge pile of same.

This is not necessarily true, as you will still have thermohaline circulation driven by evaporation. Or you will if the land mass is of significant size I guess. If it's not then the rain will all fall back on the ocean surface and cancel out the evaporation, so you won't get much in the way of circulation I guess.

@N.Virgo Not with that little time to get the temperature of the surface water up, there will be two terminator sweeps in a matter of seconds, the solar intensity isn't high enough to create a meaningful energy budget..

@Ash I'm assuming you still have radiation from the top of the atmosphere into space. The atmosphere is transparent, so you will still have that the sun heats the surface more than the atmosphere, which drives atmospheric cycling, which drives the water cycle, because when air rises it causes precipitation, acting as a dehumidifier. None of this requires a daily cycle or any kind of spatial hererogeieity, it only requires that the average EM spectrum of the sky deviates from a black body spectrum, e.g. the light source provides lots of near infra-red but little far-infrared.

In other words, most of the energy budget for Earth's weather is driven by vertical gradients, not horizontal ones. The horizontal ones will be absent here, but the vertical ones will still be present and can still drive cycling. Horizontal gradients can be created from vertical ones by spontaneous symmetry breaking, e.g. the formation of convection cells.

If you have a 1AU-square flat plane, you WILL have temperature differences across it. Large ones.

@N.Virgo The rate of motion of the "sun" is such that you have minutes of reasonably direct daylight at any given location, seconds of peak intensity, followed by hours of darkness and cooling, there's no time to build up heat anywhere in the system. That kind of circulation takes gigajoules of energy absorption in a relatively (geographically speaking) small space to get started and maintain, megajoules per square metre, at tropical intensity ~1500W, this place is getting, maybe, a few tens of kilojoules per metre.

@Ash the rate of motion of the sun is completely irrelevant to the build up of a vertical temperature gradient. It could shine all day every day and it would still happen. What matters is that the surface is being heated by shorter wavelengths that travel through the atmosphere and heat the ground while the upper atmosphere is being cooled by the emission of longer wavelengths to which the atmosphere is opaque. These two things can happen at the same time, and when the Sun is shining on Earth they do happen at the same time. Cooling happens continuously, not just at night.

Obviously it depends on the properties of the light source and the space it's in, but since this is an invented world those can be anything. If the light provides a lot of energy in short IR/visible wavelengths but almost none in the long IR wavelengths (thus allowing those to radiate away at the top of the atmosphere even when the light is heating the ground) then you can pump about as much energy into the system as you want, regardless of day length.

(Source: I was a scientist doing research on atmospheric dynamics for about 1.5 years before moving on to other fields.)

@N.Virgo The OP did state he wanted to use a source with same output as the sun. I'm more concerned with total energy budget than radiant effects on different levels of the atmosphere/ocean. That is affected by the rate of motion, I started thinking of this as the equator at equinox but on fast forward; it's more like the arctic circle at midwinter, the sun skimming past too fast to warm anything before it's gone again. Atmospheric scattering is going to make the flat plain an optically curved surface with a limit on light penetration and visibility regardless of local apparent transparency.

@Ash ah ok. Total output about equal to a tropical day on Earth. Supposing that the light has a similar spectrum to the sun and that the space above is cold, that means the weather will have about the same total energy input as a tropical summer. This is because the energy source for ordinary weather mostly is the differing radiant effects at different levels, so you can't ignore it if you're interested in the energy budget. On the other hand, there will be no jet streams or trade winds, as you do need horizontal gradients (and Coriolis forces) for those. I should probably write an answer.

@N.Virgo I think an answer from you would be quite valuable. That's the thing though the sunlight intensity is the same as the tropics but the "day" at any given spot is going to be drastically shorter as the sun shoots across the heavens at a ground speed that is the better part of Mach 11,000.

Water has a really high heat capacity, which is why a lot of coastal regions have milder climates than continental interiors. In this case, you clearly have a lot of water, so it's likely that most temperature variation would get sort of just evened out. Depending somewhat on the overall/average temperature of the ocean, you might see differing levels of humidity at various points in the day where you'd otherwise see temperature variation... but I'm not 100% sure on that. It'd probably have to be on the warmer side.
Increased humidity is more particles in the air, so even without much temperature variation there is a world where you could have small pressure differentials, with higher pressure where you have more energy entering the system.
In any case, the dominant characteristic of this place no matter what is likely to be a mild and largely unchanging climate.
